# Nav-burger collapse onclick

Tags: html5, css3

Boa tarde, procuro quem me ajude a transformar um nav-burger do fontawesome (fa-fa-bars) em X quando é feito um click e vice-versa.

Comment: Tem um exemplo aq usando o animate (Style 2 – Animate To “X”): http://callmenick.com/post/animating-css-only-hamburger-menu-icons

Answer (score 2):

É só adicionar um `eventListener` e trocar a classe do elemento validando se o menu se encontra aberto (então está fechando e deve-se trocar para `fa-close`) ou não (está abrindo e deve-se trocar para `fa-bars`).

Fica um exemplo simplório de presente.

```js
var aberto = false;

document.getElementById('troca').addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.className  = aberto ? "fa fa-close" : "fa fa-bars";
  aberto = !aberto;
});
```

```css
div { font-size: 50px; }
span { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div> <!-- Isto é só pra mudar o tamanho do ícone -->
    <span id="troca" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Já consegui resolver, obrigado